# Wordpress/PHP - Custom action on comment post

Tags: php, wordpress, comments, action, hook

Whenever a user posts a comment, I'd like to basically have a copy of the post sent to another database for a separate site. The database part is simple, but I can't seem to find the right action hook for this. (I did my testing with a simple echo statement, a failure being it not displaying at all) 'comment_save_pre' would only work when updating a comment, 'wp_set_comment_status' only works when the comment is approved, and 'comment_post' didn't seem to work at all. Does the hook exist?

```
add_action('...?...', 'on_comment_post');

function on_comment_post($comment){
     echo "Test";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`comment_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Comment.2C_Ping.2C_and_Trackback_Actions) :

> Runs just after a comment is saved in the database. Action function
>   arguments: comment ID, approval status ("spam", or 0/1 for
>   disapproved/approved).